# jQuery event on attribute change

Tags: jquery, html

I need a function to run when a divs data-page-index attribute changes

```
  var active = $('.swipeview-active'),
      dpi =  parseInt(active.attr('data-page-index')),
      left = $('[data-page-index="' +prev+ '"]').children("img").eq(0),
      right = $('[data-page-index="' +next+ '"]').children("img").eq(0);

    $(active.attr('data-page-index')).change(function(){

    right.clone( true ). css({'z-index': 5}). fadeIn(2000).appendTo('#right');
    left.clone( true ). css({'z-index': 5}). fadeIn(2000).appendTo('#left');
    });
```

I tried the change() function but that only seems to work with input fields,

```
    $(active.attr('data-page-index')).change(function(){
```

is there another way of achieving this? Thanks.

Comment: I used this the other day, http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/ pretty decent plugin.

Comment: check the answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781778/detecting-attribute-change-of-value-of-an-attribute-i-made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you still have to manipulate the DOM to trigger the event?  If so, you can manipulate a hidden input's value instead of manipulating other elements' data attributes. Then you can use the `change` trigger.

```
  var active = $('.swipeview-active'),
      dpi =  parseInt(active.attr('data-page-index')),
      left = $('[data-page-index="' +prev+ '"]').children("img").eq(0),
      right = $('[data-page-index="' +next+ '"]').children("img").eq(0),
      dpiInput = $('.swipeview-active input:hide');

  dpiInput.change(function(){
    right.clone( true ). css({'z-index': 5}). fadeIn(2000).appendTo('#right');
    left.clone( true ). css({'z-index': 5}). fadeIn(2000).appendTo('#left');
  });
```

trigger:

```
$('.swipeview-active input:hide').val(1).trigger('change');
```