# Jquery -Trigger event when the id of the div changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the extension and that extension changes the Id of the div time and again but we cannot know when the div's id is changed. But the thing is that I have to trigger a event when that id is changed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to get the "changing event" from the extension, this is by far easier, I guess. What kind of extension are you using?

Comment: the extension code is in encrypt form So I cannot find that.

Comment: Take a look in [firing event on DOM attribute change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change) that may help you.

Comment: If that extension does not provide the changed event, you can have a look at existing questions regarding change events for attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781778/detecting-attribute-change-of-value-of-an-attribute-i-made, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262348/jquery-event-on-attribute-change; furthermore there is a jQuery plugin for attribute change events: http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/, maybe you can have a look into that.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan rather then the link if you know can you give me the exact solution

Comment: Everything you need to know is in that link - and in far more detail than I can fit in to this box.

Comment: I read the thing there but it has things for the other attributes but not for the attribute id change @Rory McCrossan

Comment: That same method can be applied to any attribute.